# C - Why does the 'address of' operator return an integer value of a variable, regardless of variable type?

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings, memory-address

I was doing some practice with strings of different types and returning their address so I could understand the concept of pointer arithmetic better.

I noticed that when using the printf function, and %p as the reference character, the address would increment by 4 + 1 bytes when using the & operand on the variable, and by 1 byte without it.

Here is an example of my code and it's output:

```
 1 #include <stdio.h>
 2 #include <string.h>
 3 
 4 
 5 int main ()
 6 {
 7 char charString_1[] = "Hello";
 8 printf("%s\t%s\t %p\t %p\n", charString_1 + 1, charString_1 + 1, &charString_1 + 1, charString_1 + 1);
```

The output was the following
`ello   ello     0x7ffe76aba5d0  0x7ffe76aba5cb`

Looking at the last two hex numbers only, the address is 203 and 208 (in decimal) respectively. So the latter is a char + int value bigger than the former. if I increment by two (&charString_1 + 2) , the gap is now 2(char + int) = 10 bytes.

I understand this question might be ridiculous, but my search results have turned up nothing. I'm trying to understand how memory works, and become better at finding common faults in buggy code.

Answer (score 5):

When you do arithmetic on a pointer, the 'base unit size' is the size of the object pointed to.

So, for `char_string`, which points to a `char` (size = 1), the `+ 1` operation adds *just one*.

However, the expression `&char_string` evaluates as a pointer **to an array**, which (in your example) has a size of **six** characters (including the `nul` terminator), so the `+ 1` operation on *that* adds 6.

The difference in values printed by your two `%p` fields (5) is the difference between those two sizes (6 - 1 = 5). If you change the length of the array (e.g. like `char charString_1[] = "Hello, World!";`) you will see a corresponding change in the value of `&charString_1 + 1`.

Comment: `&char_string` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer. Adding 1 to it adjusts the address by the size of the array, not by the size of a pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Eek! What an horrendous error I made there! Thanks for pointing it out - and duly corrected.

Comment: edit** 
Eric -- but isn't the first element of an array a pointer regardless, which would be invoked by the variable char_string itself?, I would be locating the address of THE address of the pointer with &char_string, which is still char_string[0], no?

Comment: @ndryorku96 No. An array pointer points at a specific object (an array) with a particular size. Check the 'experiment' I added in my updated answer (change the "Hello" string) - you will see.

Comment: @ndryorku96: No, the first element of an array is not a pointer, unless the array is an array of pointers. After `char charString_1[] = "Hello";`, the identifier `charString_1` designates an array of six `char`. When `charString_1` is used in an expression, it is, in most circumstances, automatically **converted** to a pointer to its first element. This pointer is not in the array. The compiler is able to generate the pointer because it knows where the array is, so it can load or calculate the address. However, this conversion does not occur if the array is an operand of `sizeof` or unary `&`.

Comment: @ndryorku96: So, in `&charString_1`, the array is not converted to a pointer. The `&` takes the address of the array. So `&charString_1` is a pointer to an array, with type `char (*)[6]`, meaning it is a pointer to an array of six `char`.

Comment: Just confirmed this by assigning "hello world" to charString_1 like @adrianMole said. It was just coincidence that the size increment in the original was also the same size of an integer/pointer type -- **the relationship of how it was incrementing has to do with the size of the array, and not the data type char**. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"+1" will add the size of one of whatever type the compiler determines it is working with. In one case it believes it is working with a char, so it will add one byte (one "sizeof" a char). In the other case, it determines it is working with a pointer, so it will add one "sizeof" a pointer (typically 4 bytes).

(Edit: See below for the correction by Eric Postpischil, who points out that it actually sizeof pointer vs sizeof array)

Comment: `&char_string` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer. Adding 1 to it adjusts the address by the size of the array, not by the size of a pointer.